# Gradle execution fails: Unknown command-line option '--daemon'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I use latest Android Studio (0.8.2). On my other PC the same code is successfully builded.

It means that build scripts are correct.

So I assume that it is something with Gradle configuration, but I double rechecked all configs:

- I completely removed .gradle folder under C:\Windows\Users{MyUser}.gradle to delete old configurations;
- gradle.properties file doesn`t have any uncommented options

[image]

What do I miss?

**NOTE! I have not specified '--daemon' option. Or I only think so:( I can`t find it in Gradle default and project specific settings**

Also I created absolutely new project in the studio. It didn`t help - the same error(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is very simple. It seems that new version of Android studio imported all setting from previous one. Some of old options added additional options to compiler

[image: Reason of the issue]

Comment: Just to clarify (for other users), the solution seems to be to remove these command line options, or at least the `--daemon` one.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio always uses a Gradle daemon. It connects to the daemon via the Gradle Tooling API, and perhaps the latter doesn't understand `--daemon` (because it's redundant).

Comment: Ok. But I don`t add any additional command-line options (even '--daemon'). What should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: I thought you had specified that option. Check that you are using latest Android Studio and a compatible Gradle version (try with latest supported). If that doesn't help, file an issue.

Comment: Time to try with a minimal Gradle build, or to file an issue.